# JavaScript displayed time is different on two devices (Apple-Windows)

Tags: javascript, ios, google-chrome, time, safari

I'm currently working on a website that runs on various devices (Apple, Windows, smartphone, tablet, laptop). From my backend PHP script, datetimevalues in string format are sent to my JavaScript. When I run this code on my laptop (Windows-Chrome) I got a different time than when I ran it on my smartphone (Apple - Safari). On my smartphone it shows an hour too much. How can I fix this to get the same values to process in further code? I would like to keep the PHP as it is if possible.

PHP string value:

```
2019-01-01 01:00:00
```

On my webpage I've tested this code,

```
var phpValue = "<?php echo $tijdCountdownPauze; ?>";
var phpValueSplitted = phpValue.split(" "); 
var phpvalueCombine = phpValueSplitted[0] + "T" + phpValueSplitted[1];
var phpValueCombinedDate = new Date(phpvalueCombine);
document.write(phpValueCombinedDate);
document.write("<br>");
```

Output of Windows laptop in Chrome:

```
Tue Jan 01 2019 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Midden-Europese standaardtijd)
```

Output of Apple iPhone in Safari:

```
Tue Jan 01 2019 02:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
```

Comment: You should use yyyy/MM/dd format, then they become equal.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply! unfortunatly this doens't work. maybe I do something wrong..... `const search = '-';
const replaceWith = '/';

var phpValue = "<?php echo $tijdCountdownPauze; ?>";
var phpValueReplaced = phpValue.split(search).join(replaceWith);
var phpValueSplitted = phpValueReplaced.split(" "); 
var phpvalueCombine = phpValueSplitted[0] + "T" + phpValueSplitted[1];
alert(phpvalueCombine);
var countDownDate = new Date(phpvalueCombine);
document.write(phpValueOK);
`

Comment: @DevanshBaldwa Thank you for capitalizing: there was just a few more to fix, ah ah. You can see my subsequent edit.

Comment: @sebastiaan One browser is reading **01:00:00** as local time (GMT+1 for you), the other is reading it as GMT+0 time and then displaying it as local time (GMT+1 for you). The major issue being that you didn't clearly define what was the original timezone from which to interpret the date.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47898911/convert-time-hhmmss-into-gmt-time-format-in-angular-2

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213222/convert-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmmss-ms-gmt-to-local-time-using-javascript

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `Z` (or [any other timezone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse#Using_Date.parse)) to the time string.

```
phpValueSplitted[0] + "T" + phpValueSplitted[1] + "Z"
// or
phpValueSplitted[0] + "T" + phpValueSplitted[1] + "+00:00"
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'm almost sure that this question should be closed as duplicate of another one instead of answering it.

Comment: @Cœur Agree. But I can't do it without enough reputation

Comment: I believe you can _flag_ a question for closure when at early reputation.